# How to display a .ppt in a web browser?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I've tried to put a ppt file into my website (.aspx). I used a Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint namespace and it works fine but I want to display my presentation just in a web browser (especially IE, in a frame or something like this), not in a separate window. Is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: Here are 5 ways to help you [put your PowerPoint presentation on Web](http://www.sameshow.com/other/5-ways-put-powerpoint-presentation-on-web.html#110), hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Convert ppt to flash, then embed the flash to the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Upload the document to [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/) and embed their viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Use href in case of link or src for frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply link to the PPT file, and the user's machine has PPT installed, then following the link should open it in the same browser window. Otherwise, they'll need to download and install the free PPT viewer (available from [microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=powerpoint+viewer)). If they don't have either full PowerPoint or the viewer, it will ask them where to download your PPT file to (and they won't be able to open it).

Alternatively, for portability, you may consider saving your PPT as a series of JPG or PNG images (in PowerPoint go to "File">"Save As" and set "Save as type:" to JPEG or PNG). However, you will loose any slide transitions, sounds and effects, and I'm not sure if there's a way to batch-save all slides using this method.

Or, you could go to "File">"Save as Web Page" (and you may wish to choose the "Publish" button for more options). However, I don't know if this will even keep your layout, maybe only your slide outline/content.

It all depends on your PPT presentation and target audience. Most people have either Microsoft Office or OpenOffice.org, but a link to the viewer on your refering page would be a good idea.