# Powerpoint viewer for react?

Tags: reactjs, powerpoint, presentation, contentpresenter

I searched a lot for this but couldn't find any package or a guide on how to view a ".ppt" file on a webpage using react.js.

I'm allowing the user to upload a ".ppt" file, and I want him to be able to view that "Powerpoint" file in a web page, is that even possible?

I tried the following but it didn't work ...

```
<iframe
    src={`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[${linkToPPTFile}]`}
    width="100%"
    height="600px"
    frameBorder="0"
></iframe>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this similar issue. The problem is with this part `src=[${linkToPPTFile}]` of your iframe src. Remove the box brackets. It should just be:

```
<iframe
    src={`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=${linkToPPTFile}`}
    width="100%"
    height="600px"
    frameBorder="0"
>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for an answer for this for a while and stumbled upon a solution that I think might work for your case too. I used the react-doc-viewer library that enables you to display multiple file types like ppt, word, excel and many more. You can install it with npm, further instructions on this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-doc-viewer and simply create a custom viewer component that you can reuse for your files.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that particular Microsoft embed link no longer works. One way to make it happen is to store the PowerPoint file in a public folder online and create an embed code in PowerPoint for the Web (https://www.office.com/launch/powerpoint). The embed code should include an `<iframe/>` tag.

There's more information about the process here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-a-presentation-in-a-web-page-or-blog-19668A1D-2299-4AF3-91E1-AE57AF723A60

Comment: Just re-read the question. I will look to see if it's possible for a user-uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have backend, it is built with node.js and you will have full control over production server (i.e. able to install software there), you can try to covert to png using [ppt-png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ppt-png) package. Under the hood it uses libreoffice for ppt-pdf conversion and then imagemagick for pdf-png conversion and this is the best approach to task.

Comment: I think this could be the only way to go about it, and I do have control over the backend, however, it is built with PHP :(. I'll try to figure out how to do it server-side and send back the PNGs to the frontend.

Comment: @Ruby combining these two libraries might do the trick: [office-converter](https://github.com/ncjoes/office-converter), [pdf-to-image](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image). They use the same principle and require to install libreoffice, imagick and ghostscript

Answer (score 0):

There's some similar information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356660/how-to-display-a-ppt-in-a-web-browser).

From what I read it seems like you could either convert the powerpoints to flash and display those, or potentially use some sort of tool like slideshare or a google slides extension.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, these options won't work for my case. Thanks for the effort thought :)

Answer (score 0):

The only possible user-uploaded PPT solution I could find involves uploading a copy of the file to One Drive, using Microsoft's API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/upload?view=odsp-graph-online

You could then create a "sharing link" using the API. The URL to the shared file is returned in the API response (https://1drv.ms/...) and anyone using the link can access the document to view it online. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: That won't work for me, I need a way to display the ppt file directly (coming as a link from an API response) or somehow convert that file to an array of images to display it as a slider.

Comment: It looks as though it's possible to create an "embed" version of the link using "createLink" once your copy the file to One Drive via the API.

Comment: Yes maybe but that would require repurchasing a space on OneDrive and that would lead to another level of complications.

Comment: If you would prefer to convert PPTX files to images, there seems to be a slew of options on github (https://github.com/search?q=ppt+to+image) and some commercial APIs (https://developers.zamzar.com/).

Comment: Do you have a code example on converting PPT files to images?

Comment: Sorry, no I don't.